# NSData length is zero

Tags: objective-c

I have this :

```
  NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"Flower.jpg"];
    NSLog(@"l:%lu",(unsigned long)[imageData length]);
```

Where the image is in my project .

the log show a `length` of zero.
why is that ?

Comment: Make sure you have `Flower.jpg` image in project.

Comment: of course i have it in my project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an absolute path as your argument, not just the file name:

> `+ (id)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` 
>   *path* 
>   The absolute path of the file from which to read data.

```
NSString *absolutePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Flower" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:absolutePath];
NSLog(@"l:%lu",(unsigned long)[imageData length]);
```

Comment: what does it means? the file is in my project- i drag it in there. how would i define a path ?

Comment: I didn't have enough additional information to write my own answer, so just hijacked yours. Hope that's ok! :P

Comment: @JamesWebster Thanks. Was about to expand mine. You were faster :)